# Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE:repackage failed: Source must refer to an existing file

Tags: java, spring, maven

This is my first project using Spring (and I'm not too experienced with Maven either) and I get the error in the title when running `mvn package`.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hu.infolaverage.europress.imageprovider</groupId>
    <artifactId>imageprovider</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>hu.infolaverage.europress.imageprovider.App</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

And here is the full error:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building imageprovider 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ imageprovider ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ imageprovider ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.451 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-06T09:06:49+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/167M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project imageprovider: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE:repackage failed: Source must refer to an existing file -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project imageprovider: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE:repackage failed: Source must refer to an existing file
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE:repackage failed: Source must refer to an existing file
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source must refer to an existing file
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.<init>(Repackager.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo$1.<init>(RepackageMojo.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.execute(RepackageMojo.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Same thing happens when I remove the `version` and `executions` from the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, I found the error. I needed to change the `packaging` parameter to `jar` from `pom`. Also, the `repositories`, `pluginRepositories`, the `maven-compiler-plugin` and the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`'s `version` and `executions` weren't needed.

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help others who run into the same issues as I :) don't like to be DenverCoder9 :D

Answer (score 94):

Try `mvn install` before running `spring-boot:repackage`:

```
mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage
```

Comment: Well, actually that worked for me. I used `mvn spring-boot:repackage` and got `Source must refer to an existing file`. Using `mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage` made it work.

Comment: `mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage` also worked for me.

Comment: @sjngm your answer was definitely the best one.

Comment: @snjgm your comment should be the answer, and this worked for me, thanks!

Comment: you can also just do 'package' before hand instead of install... `mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage`

Answer (score 5):

Just adding my experience :

After none of the suggested solutions worked. I figured out there was some issue with the downloaded spring-boot-maven-plugin in the .m2 folder. Deleting the plugin and allowing the "mvn clean install" to re-download and build worked.

Comment: Yes .. worked with me .. manually delete all the files in .`m2\repository` folder and then run `mvn -clean install`

Answer (score 2):

For me, the trick was reinstalling all dependencies.

This can be done in two ways:

- using `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` to delete all local dependencies
- just deleting everything in the m2/repository folder,
  I suggest you use the mvn command.

Then, follow it up by a `mvn clean install` to load all the dependencies again.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is multi-module, bear in mind where the app class is. I had to do 3 things to make this work:

1. As always when you do a significant change in your pom, from your IDE do a Maven > update project.
2. As suggested by other people:

   ```
   mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage
   ```
3. It still did not work... from the parent pom of my app. My app is moltimodule, with one of the modules having the Spring Application class. Only when I run the repackage goal from that module I get my fat jar properly generated, otherwise I am getting:

`Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:repackage failed: Unable to find main class`

because the build starts with the modules the one having the main class depend on, and, of course, they do not hold the main class of the app.

I am still investigating why, because I want to have my project built in one shot as per the reactor dependency detection, rather than doing it in 2 shots, which apart from ugly is quite inconvenient for CI automation.

Comment: And here is the hint for my issue 3 above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187588/spring-boot-multi-module-maven-project-repackage-failed

Answer (score 0):

The exact error message in my case was this one:

> Failed to execute goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.14.RELEASE:repackage
> invalid entry size (expected 1 but got 0 bytes)

I was about to create an empty clean Spring Boot project and wanted to build it, to see if everything was good. I found out that error was caused by the presence of en empty **application.properties** file. It was created but there was no any text in it. After I added a property (example, server.port: 19999), the project was built successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was API incompatibility exception.
Since I did not specify the version in the plugin, the plugin was looking for the latest version which was not compatible, you have to specify the version explicitly for the plugin `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

Refer to [Unable to load the mojo ‘repackage’ in the plugin spring-boot-maven-plugin due to an API incompatibility](https://spigandoeaprendendo.wordpress.com/2022/03/08/java-11-maven-spring-boot-erro-repackage-failed-unable-to-load-the-mojo-repackage-in-the-plugin-spring-boot-maven-plugin-due-to-an-api-incompatibility/)

Answer (score -1):

I added to the `pom.xml` this configuration

```
<plugins>
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
.
.
.
</plugins>
```

[Source](https://programmersought.com/article/55111298177/)

Answer (score -2):

If you are using intelliJ community, nothing listed will work. I switched to Eclipse and was able to run a spring project with the default settings from start.spring.io with while making no changes to the POM file or any settings. It seems intelliJ community makes a confusing mess out of spring projects.

In short try another IDE before going through with any changes. The start.spring.io setup should work as its packaged.

Comment: Maven runs IDE agnostic.

Answer (score -3):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: can you please comment your code and explain your answer ?