# Executing individual maven plugin goals in multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm trying to overcome well-known maven issue, described in various SO questions, for example:

- [Maven exec:java goal on a multi-module project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091311/maven-execjava-goal-on-a-multi-module-project)
- [Spring Boot Multi-Module maven project repackage failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187588/spring-boot-multi-module-maven-project-repackage-failed)

before now I was familiar with following workarounds:

- `mvn install` - that is exactly what I would like to avoid
- extremely comprehensive project configuration involving `<skip>`/`<properties>`/`<profiles>`
- copy dependencies using `maven-dependency-plugin` into module folder whilst packaging and setup `classpath`

and all of those workarounds looks very poor from my perspective.

Today I have read about [root-reactor aware subfolder builds](https://maarten.mulders.it/2020/11/whats-new-in-maven-4/#root-reactor-aware-subfolder-builds) in `maven-4`, however `maven-4` is not yet released and I'm interested to get a solution for `maven-3`. I have performed some research and have found a couple useful extension points in `maven-3`:

[DefaultArtifactResolver.java](https://github.com/apache/maven-resolver/blob/master/maven-resolver-impl/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/internal/impl/DefaultArtifactResolver.java#L312):

```java
if ( workspace != null )
{
    File file = workspace.findArtifact( artifact );
    if ( file != null )
    {
        artifact = artifact.setFile( file );
        result.setArtifact( artifact );
        result.setRepository( workspace.getRepository() );
        artifactResolved( session, trace, artifact, result.getRepository(), null );
        continue;
    }
}
```

[DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/project/DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java#L98)

```java
for ( RepositorySessionDecorator decorator : decorators )
{
    RepositorySystemSession decorated = decorator.decorate( project, session );
    if ( decorated != null )
    {
        session = decorated;
    }
}
```

and finally I have implemented a very simple maven extension (full source code on [github](https://github.com/andreybpanfilov/fakerepo)):

```java
@Component(role = RepositorySessionDecorator.class)
public class FakeRepositorySessionDecorator implements RepositorySessionDecorator {

    @Requirement
    protected ArtifactHandlerManager artifactHandlerManager;

    @Override
    public RepositorySystemSession decorate(MavenProject project, RepositorySystemSession session) {
        String enabled = session.getUserProperties().get("fakerepo");
        if (!"true".equalsIgnoreCase(enabled)) {
            return null;
        }
        MavenProject root = project;
        while (root != null && !root.isExecutionRoot()) {
            root = root.getParent();
        }
        if (root != null) {
            WorkspaceReader workspaceReader = session.getWorkspaceReader();
            workspaceReader = new FakeWorkspaceReader(workspaceReader, root, artifactHandlerManager);
            return new DefaultRepositorySystemSession(session)
                    .setWorkspaceReader(workspaceReader);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The idea is if developer specifies `-Dfakeroot` when executing maven plugin goal my extension expands `workspace` scope from `single module` to the `project root` and when requested new expanded workspace tries to find packaged artifact among submodule folders, thus the sequence of commands like:

```
mvn clean package
mvn exec:exec -pl submodule -Dfakeroot
```

leads developer to the expected result.

**The question is**: what I may brake if I remove requirement to specify `-Dfakerepo` and enable the behaviour described above by default (i.e. apply new behaviour for all maven goals and lifecycle phases)? From my perspective it is always more reasonable to lookup packaged artifacts among submodule folders rather than in local repository. Or am I missing something?

---

UPD.

I have found a following hypothetical scenario when my extension may work not like "expected":

- let there are two submodules `A` and `B` in multi-module project, and `B` depends on `A`
- developer have modified at least `A` and issues something like `mvn -am test -pl B`

in that case if `A` was packaged previously my extension forces maven to use stale artifact, however [default implementation](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/ReactorReader.java#L185) would use `A/target/classes` as classpath entry, on the other hand `A/target/classes` may contain stale classes (we are not issuing `clean`), thus the behaviour of "default implementation" is also far from ideal in that case.

---

UPD2.

It seems that it is worth to explain why I that issue is bothering me. Actually, there are a couple of "typical" scenarios:

1. developers would like to maintain their own infrastructure (in particular that is primarily a DB), i.e.: start and stop multiple instances, perform DB migrations, debug, etc - hereby we would like to avoid CI issues like "something went wrong in CI pipeline - guess what". And the goal is to make it as simple as possible, for example we have a special `exec` goal in `dev` submodule, which performs DB migrations:

```xml
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>tld.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>another-submodule</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>

<execution>
    <id>liquibase-update-primary</id>
    <phase>install</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <!-- expecting to get module dependencies there -->
            <classpath/>
            <!-- main class -->
            <argument>liquibase.integration.commandline.Main</argument>
            <!-- covered by project properties -->
            <argument>--changeLogFile=${primary.changeLogFile}</argument>
            <!-- covered by profile properties -->
            <argument>--url=${jdbc.url}</argument>
            <argument>--driver=${jdbc.driver}</argument>
            <argument>--username=${jdbc.username}</argument>
            <argument>--password=${jdbc.password}</argument>
            <argument>--logLevel=info</argument>
            <argument>update</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

and that obviously does not work in `maven-3`, because it expects to find `tld.project-another-submodule` artifact in local repository, however it is possible to perform the following trick with `maven-dependency-plugin`:

```xml
<execution>
    <id>liquibase-dependencies</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>copy</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
                <!-- 
                    now we may tell liquibase to load extra jars
                    from  ${project.build.directory}/liquibase
                -->
                <groupId>tld.project</groupId>
                <artifactId>another-submodule</artifactId>
                <type>jar</type>
                <destFileName>another-submodule.jar</destFileName>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/liquibase</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

2. We would like to run integration tests individually without recompiling/packaging the entire project i.e. issuing something like `mvn verify -pl it-submodule`, that is both useful from developer and CI perspective:

   - Developers and DevOps may perform infrastructure-related steps somewhere between `package` and `verify` phases
   - CI may run `verify` multiple times (yep, someone may think about how is it possible to reiterate failed tests in CI pipeline, however our goal is to run `verify` phase multiple times in a row to make sure there are no flapping tests)
3. In case of large projects every extra lifecycle step takes a lot of time

Comment: First `copy dependencies using maven-dependency-plugin into module folder whilst packaging and setup classpath` that sounds a bit strange... please show the project or a link to it. `mvn install - that is exactly what I would like to avoid` You can write that you like to avoid that but there is no other way at the moment. Also the question is why do you like to use exec plugin for a spring boot project and what would be the problem just to do `mvn package` and `java -jar module/target/xyz-jar` ???

Comment: @khmarbaise Karl, I'm not asking about how to do that in maven - I already know that two java classes solve all my troubles, I'm asking about possible consequences of overriding default behaviour.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I end up with the following:

1. I doubt this feature will be implemented in maven in the observable future, so implementing my own maven extension makes sense, here it is: [GitHub](https://github.com/andreybpanfilov/inter-module-helper), [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tel.panfilov.maven/inter-module-extension)
2. Two modes were implemented:

   - installing reactor artifacts into "temporary local repository" - by doing that we do not poison `local repository` and performing `mvn install` is now "safe". `-Dimh.repository` system property enables this mode
   - expanding reactor workspace to the entire project, like `maven-4` does, but also paying attention to supplemental artifacts, `mvn install` is not required in this case and `mvn package` is enough. `-Dimh.workspace` system property enables this mode

Examples below are based on [MNG-7527](https://github.com/andreybpanfilov/MNG-7527) project

`-Dimh.repository` mode:

```
% mvn clean install -Dimh.repository| grep Installing
[INFO] Installing MNG-7527/pom.xml to /Users/apanfilov/.m2/repository/../../work/gh/MNG-7527/target/local-repo/tel/panfilov/maven/mng7527/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mng7527-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing MNG-7527/mng7527-war/target/mng7527-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to /Users/apanfilov/.m2/repository/../../work/gh/MNG-7527/target/local-repo/tel/panfilov/maven/mng7527-war/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mng7527-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing MNG-7527/mng7527-war/pom.xml to /Users/apanfilov/.m2/repository/../../work/gh/MNG-7527/target/local-repo/tel/panfilov/maven/mng7527-war/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mng7527-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing MNG-7527/mng7527-war/target/mng7527-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar to /Users/apanfilov/.m2/repository/../../work/gh/MNG-7527/target/local-repo/tel/panfilov/maven/mng7527-war/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mng7527-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar
[INFO] Installing MNG-7527/mng7527-dep1/target/mng7527-dep1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/apanfilov/.m2/repository/../../work/gh/MNG-7527/target/local-repo/tel/panfilov/maven/mng7527-dep1/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mng7527-dep1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing MNG-7527/mng7527-dep1/pom.xml to /Users/apanfilov/.m2/repository/../../work/gh/MNG-7527/target/local-repo/tel/panfilov/maven/mng7527-dep1/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mng7527-dep1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing MNG-7527/mng7527-dep2/target/mng7527-dep2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/apanfilov/.m2/repository/../../work/gh/MNG-7527/target/local-repo/tel/panfilov/maven/mng7527-dep2/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mng7527-dep2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing MNG-7527/mng7527-dep2/pom.xml to /Users/apanfilov/.m2/repository/../../work/gh/MNG-7527/target/local-repo/tel/panfilov/maven/mng7527-dep2/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mng7527-dep2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom

% mvn clean package -f mng7527-dep1 -Dimh.repository
[INFO] [IMH] workspace extension disabled
[INFO] [IMH] setting up overlay repository
[INFO] [IMH] using root project target folder as overlay repository: MNG-7527/target/local-repo
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< tel.panfilov.maven:mng7527-dep1 >-------------------
[INFO] Building mng7527-dep1 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] Deleting MNG-7527/mng7527-dep1/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory MNG-7527/mng7527-dep1/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory MNG-7527/mng7527-dep1/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] Building jar: MNG-7527/mng7527-dep1/target/mng7527-dep1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`-Dimh.workspace` mode:

```
% mvn clean package -f mng7527-dep1 -Dimh.workspace 
[INFO] [IMH] repository extension disabled
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< tel.panfilov.maven:mng7527-dep1 >-------------------
[INFO] Building mng7527-dep1 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] Deleting MNG-7527/mng7527-dep1/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory MNG-7527/mng7527-dep1/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory MNG-7527/mng7527-dep1/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ mng7527-dep1 ---
[INFO] Building jar: MNG-7527/mng7527-dep1/target/mng7527-dep1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Well,

I have taken a look on [how that implemented](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/ReactorReader.java) in `maven-4` and got a conclusion that it won't work as expected:

1. maven team have expanded the scope of reactor workspace, now the scope of reactor workspace is an entire project, regardless whether `-f` or `-pl` was specified - exactly the same what I'm doing.
2. maven team have added some heuristics to determine whether packaged artifact is stale or not (simply comparing modification dates of packaged artifact and classes in `target/classes`, nothing related to sources though) - that is actually the answer to my Q.
3. there is an issue which make "root-reactor aware subfolder builds" feature completely useless and dangerous: classifiers are not supported - `maven-4` tries to pick up main artifact regardless what classifier was specified, in case of failure it falls back to `~/.m2/repository` - filed [MNG-7527](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7527)
4. if maven fails to discover main artifact it tries either `target/classes` or `target/test-classes` - in the most cases that leads to the exception "Artifact has not been packaged yet. When used on reactor artifact, copy should be executed after packaging: see MDEP-187"