# Submodule can't find parent module as dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a Maven project with a JavaFX submodule and it just started giving me an error, I can't find any changes I made to the submodule that might've caused this other than starting a git repository. I think something is wrong with the `<build>` in the submodule pom, but nothing I tried worked. The submodule pom is mostly generated by IntelliJ.

Parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>ChoreSystem</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<modules>
    <module>ChoreServer</module>
    <module>User</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ...
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Submodule pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>ChoreSystem</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>User</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>17-ea+11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>17-ea+11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>ChoreSystem</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>AppLauncher</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run the User with ```clean javafx:run```
I get this Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project User: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:User:pom:1.0.1: Failure to find org.example:ChoreSystem:jar:1.0.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Comment: That is well-known maven drawback/limitation you may either give maven a hint specifying `<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>` in `User/pom.xml/parent` element (not sure that will help) or try using my [maven extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73255826/executing-individual-maven-plugin-goals-in-multi-module-project)

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why submodule `User` should declare a dependency on the parent pom `ChoreSystem` which looks like it is there just to run a sequence of child modules. Maybe you meant to declare a dependency on `ChoreServer`.